# mysql 5.6 Linux vs windows performance

Tags: mysql

The below command takes 2-3 seconds in a Linux MySQL 5.6 server running Php 5.4

```
exec("mysql --host=$db_host --user=$db_user --password=$db_password $db_name < $sql_file");
```

On windows with similar configuration it takes 10-15 seconds. The windows machine has a lot more ram (16gb) and similar hard drive. I installed MySQL 5.6 and made no configuration changes. This is on windows server 2012.

What are configurations I can change to fix this?

The database file creates about 40 innodb tables with very minimal inserts.

EDIT: Here is the file I am running:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/uguzgbbnyghok0o/database_14.4.sql?dl=0

UPDATE: On windows 8 and 7 it was 3 seconds. But on windows server 2012 it is 15+ seconds. I disabled System center 2012 and that made no difference.

UPDATE 2:

I also tried killing almost every service except for mysql and IIS and it still performed slowly. Is there something in windows server 2012 that causes this to be slow?

Update 3
I tried disable write cache buffer flush and performance is now great.

I didn't have to do this on other machines I tested with. Does this indicate a bottleneck With how disk is setup?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/282ea0fc-fba7-4474-83d5-f9bbce0e52ea/major-disk-speed-improvement-disable-write-cache-buffer-flushing?forum=w7itproperf

Comment: i guess the first question is why are you doing this through a php script and not just from the cli?

Comment: Could be something as basic as creating files taking longer on windows than on linux. If you have `innodb_file_per_table` set. Although 10-15 seconds to create 40 files does sound a bit much.

Comment: @pala_ I tried via command line too and it is still just as slow. This script is part of an installer that loads up a database.

Comment: I think this question may be better for superusers or possibly the database stackexchange site. This doesn't really seem like a programming problem.

Comment: maybe it's filesystem brakes due to some software like antivirus.

Comment: It's rather questionable to show this as a PHP question. You're running some undisclosed SQL commands and wondering why they perform badly. You should agree that it all depends on what your SQL commands are.

Comment: I have posted the sql file.

Comment: I think there is a consensus here that file lockers are not an appropriate way to show code, since they require people to fetch stuff to help you, and links break, which may render the question less useful for future readers after you have finished with it. Would you transfer that file into your question?

Comment: Have to tried running mysql < sqlfile.sql directly in windows server?

Comment: @Murali yes just as slow

Comment: So, its not php problem then?

Answer (score 3):

That is why we call it **LAMP stack** and no doubt why it is so popular [mysql on windows vs Linux](http://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/30/what-operating-system-do-you-run-mysql-on-in-production/). But that has more to do more with stability and safety. Performance wise the difference should be minimal. While a Microsoft Professional can best tune the Windows Server explicitly for MySQL by enabling and disabling the services, but we would rather be interested to see the configuration of your `my.ini`. So what could be the contributing factors w.r.t Windows on MySQL that we should consider

1. The services and policies in Windows is sometimes a big impediment to performance because of all sorts of restrictions and protections.
2. We should also take into account the Apache(`httpd.conf`) and PHP(`php.ini`) configuration as MySQL is so tightly coupled with them.
3. Antivirus : Better disable this when benchmarking about performance
4. Must consider these parameters in `my.ini` **as here you have 40 Innodb tables**

   `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`, `query_cache_size`, `innodb_flush_method`, `innodb_log_file_size`, `innodb_file_per_table`

**For example:** If file size of ib_logfile0 = 524288000, Then
524288000/1048576 = 500, Hence innodb_log_file_size should be 500M

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-tuning.html

5. When importing data into InnoDB, make sure that MySQL does not have autocommit mode enabled because that requires a log flush to disk for every insert
   `SET autocommit=0;`
6. **Most importantly** `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` as in this case it is about importing database. Setting this to '2' form '1' (default)hm can be a big performance booster specially during data import as log buffer will be flushed to OS file cache on every transaction commit

For reference :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72766/60318

http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/

---

Lastly, based on this

`mysql --host=$db_host --user=$db_user --password=$db_password $db_name < $sql_file`

If the mysqldump (.sql) file is not residing in the same host where you are importing, performance will be slow. **Consider to copy the (.sql) file exactly in the server where you need to import the database, then try importing without `--host` option.**

Comment: Tried changing `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` to 2 from 1 and also tried 0 and it is still slow. I am starting to think there is something wrong with machine.

Comment: Item 5 (autocommit) -- If you are importing the output of `msyqldump --opt`, each `INSERT` will have hundreds or thousands of rows, so the _log_ flush is amortized pretty nicely.  DDLs force `COMMIT` always.

Comment: (Copy .sql vs --host) -- Unless you have a slow network, you might speed up the import by doing it remotely.  This is because you would be avoiding reading the .sql from the disk you are trying to write to.  (Since the "read" is coming from the network instead.)

Comment: The bottleneck is related to your network speed, forever would  be little long. You may get this also under heavy load `Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table` if done remotely

Comment: MySql has absolutely nothing to do with PHP/Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is slower at creating files, period.  40 InnoDB tables involves 40 or 80 file creations.  Since they are small InnoDB tables, you may as well set `innodb_file_per_table=OFF` before doing the `CREATEs`, thereby needing only 40 file creations.

Good practice in MySQL is to create tables once, and *not* be creating/dropping tables frequently.  If your application is designed to do lots of CREATEs, we should focus on that.  (Note that, even on Linux, table create time is non-trivial.)

If these are temporary tables...  5.7 will have significant changes that will improve the performance (on either OS) in this area.  5.7 is on the cusp of being GA.

(RAM size is irrelevant in this situation.)

Comment: I have posted the sql file. If someone with a windows computer can try the same thing maybe it is just a windows problem.

Comment: innnodb_file_per_table =OFF made it actually a bit slower

Comment: Windows is slower at creating files? Where is your proof for this?

Comment: @ChrisMuench i'm running windows 8 x64 with WAMP/Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12. The imports takes roughly about 3sec in phpmyadmin 4.1.14

Comment: @DarkBee that is what I got on windows 8 too (regular install). Does windows server have some sort of issue?

Comment: In fact there is an issue when using `localhost` to connect to the database in phpymyadmin. You can change this in the `config.inc.php` of phpmyadmin. Look for this line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` (near line 35) and change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @DarkBee I am running from MySQL console and not phpMyAdmin

Comment: Many topics suggest disabling IPv6 if MySQL is slow.

Comment: OK, lots of differences in experiences.  Let's ask "why does it matter?"  Shouldn't `CREATE TABLE` a one-time process?